# Parallelepiped inside a non-uniform Sphere

Tags: geometry, computer-science, 3d

I have a Parallelepiped which has a 3D size x, y and z I would like to know how could I get the size (x, y, z) of the non-uniform Sphere which can contains the Parallelepiped.

Here's an illustration but with a Parallelepiped and a non-uniform Sphere that fits the Parallelepiped shape.

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: orthogonal parallelepiped? $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. And what the heck is matter if it is a non-uniform sphere??

Comment: That's something I already tried but if I scale only one axis, the sphere will grow uniformly and I want to avoid that. I want to scale each axis separately.

Comment: you want an ellipsoid around it?

Comment: Off the top of my head, find the longest diagonal. This will be one axis of an enclosing ellipsoid. You should be able work out the other axis lengths from the distances of the other vertices from this diagonal.

Comment: @amd : I think the OP thinks to a solution where the ellipsoid axes are orthogonal to the parallelepiped faces (see the solution I propose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think to an ellipsoid with axes orthogonal to the faces of the parallelepiped (see figure below), here is a solution.

Consider the coordinate system with the origin at the center of the parallelepiped "box", and axes $Ox, Oy, Oz$ orthogonal to the faces of the box, piercing them at their center.

Let  $2x_0, 2y_0, 2z_0$ be the resp. side lengthes of the box. Thus the coordinates of the vertices of the box are $(\pm x_0, \pm y_0, \pm z_0)$.

Then the ellipsoid defined by the following equation :

$$\dfrac{x^2}{x_0^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{y_0^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{z_0^2}=3$$

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) passes through the 8 vertices and includes the box (see proof below).

The endpoints of this ellipsoid can be found by setting two of the three variables to zero, giving

$$(x_e=\pm \sqrt{3}x_0, 0, 0), \ \ \ \ (0, y_e=\pm \sqrt{3}y_0, 0), \ \ \ \ (0, 0, z_e=\pm \sqrt{3}z_0)$$

**Proof of inclusion :** the interior of the ellipsoid is convex. The box is the convex hull of its vertices; as such, it is included into any convex set containing these points.

[image]

Case where $x_0=3, \ y_0=2, \ z_0=1$.